# How do you test complex parent child communications using testing library

Tags: unit-testing, react-testing-library, functional-testing

I would like to understand how to test a parent component that depends on the complex logic in one child and updates another one.

1. Let's imagine we have a huge form (parent) on a page and we want to have the ability to update it.
2. When there is at least one change we should show a confirmation bar (a child) to apply the change.
3. To amend the form data we have an option to click on a button to open a modal component (a child) with a form group inside.  Moreover, the modal makes an API call to fetch some data and uses a timeout to apply new changes.

What would you test in the case?

P.S. It's easy to test each child component separately but when you try to write a functional test for the parent component then you may notice that the test is complex and unmaintainable due to async login in children

Comment: Is this a unit-test or a functional-test? If unit-test, you mock the child components. If functional-test then you don't consider child components separate at all and write test for the main form.

Comment: I would like to thank you for the reply. It makes a lot of sense for me in general. In my case it was an integration test. Now I am pretty sure that we should use something else to write functional tests because even an integration one can be expensive. Especially when you deal with async logic inside child components.